# rJava access issue in R3.3.0 (Windows XP)

Tags: r, excel

I need to use the package "xlsx" to export some data on R to excel, but that package requires rJava to run. Whenever I use `library(rJava)` to call rJava, I get the following error:

```
Error:.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package 'rJava' could not be loaded
```

I honestly cannot make heads or tails of it. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350723/rjava-not-loading-in-r

Comment: This contains both my issue, and a workable answer

Comment: An alternative (with some limitations) is [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html), not based on java.